# "...is not a function" error in Earth Engine - converting array to list

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to convert the result of a region reduction by `ee.Reducer.fixedHistogram()` to an `ee.List` object so that I can `.map()` a function over it, but I get an error:

> [object].toList is not a function

The [API doc](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#ee.reducer.fixedhistogram) for `ee.Reducer.fixedHistogram()` says that the output is an Nx2 `ee.Array` object. `ee.Array` objects have a `.toList()` method - why does it not work?

Here is my code:

```js
// Define an image - select the SWIR1 band.
var img = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR/LC08_038029_20180810')
  .select('B6');

// Define an area of interest.
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
  [[[-110.5241853160436, 44.72231727808245],
    [-110.5241853160436, 44.44355785401221],
    [-110.06001295276235, 44.44355785401221],
    [-110.06001295276235, 44.72231727808245]]], null, false);

// Show image and AOI on the map.
Map.centerObject(img, 8);  
Map.addLayer(img, {min: 100, max: 3500});
Map.addLayer(aoi);

// Calculate a histogram for the pixels in the API.
var swir1HistDict = img.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.fixedHistogram(0, 5000, 250),
  geometry: aoi,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e13
});

// A dictionary was returned, get the ee.Array results.
var swir1HistArray = swir1HistDict.get('B6');

// Convert the array to a list so that it can be mapped over.
var swir1HistList = swir1HistArray.toList();
print(swir1HistList);
```

[Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/f92eea60f38dd90e396afbf8525aafa1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the array result of the histogram explicitly as an `ee.Array` object.

```js
var swir1HistArray = ee.Array(swir1HistDict.get('B6'));
```

The issue stems from the [server vs client](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/client_server) distinction. Before your code request is run on Earth Engine servers it is translated to an execution graph (a set of instructions). For methods such as `.get()` which can return a variety of object types, the actual type returned cannot be known until the request is executed on the server. In your example, you call `.get('B6')` to get the array result from the histogram region reduction. Since the result type is ambiguous in the execution graph, an error is generated because without a known object type there can be no way to know if the `.toList()` method is available.

In general, always cast the result of `.get()` to the expected type.

Here is the correct version of your script:

```js
// Define an image.
var img = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR/LC08_038029_20180810')
  .select('B6');

// Define an area of interest.
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
  [[[-110.5241853160436, 44.72231727808245],
    [-110.5241853160436, 44.44355785401221],
    [-110.06001295276235, 44.44355785401221],
    [-110.06001295276235, 44.72231727808245]]], null, false);

// Show image and AOI on the map.
Map.centerObject(img, 8);  
Map.addLayer(img, {min: 100, max: 3500});
Map.addLayer(aoi);

// Calculate a histogram for the pixels in the API.
var swir1HistDict = img.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.fixedHistogram(0, 5000, 250),
  geometry: aoi,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e13
});

// A dictionary was returned, get the ee.Array results.
var swir1HistArray = ee.Array(swir1HistDict.get('B6'));

// Convert the array to a list so that it can be mapped over.
var swir1HistList = swir1HistArray.toList();
print(swir1HistList);
```

[Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/93d1f0073e9dbe8d122755de16004017)